# Simple validation in button click action using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KLrs6/581/)

Here the validation should happen once the button is clicked, it is ok. But i have written the validation for field 1, field 3.

Once i have pressed the button it is showing the validate error for first field only and the field 3 error is displayed only when i keypress the field 3.

Note : It is working in local but while i use the jsfiddle it is not working

The below script should be added to work in local

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://expirebox.com/files/88b64e3d9a74823c8b1e6b8f60091917.js"></script>
```

What is the mistake in the validation and how can i fix this ?

Comment: Fiddle has Only 1 textbox Contrary to your question where there are 3 textboxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change from `id=...` to `name=...` for `field1`:

```
     Field 1: <input name="field1" type="text" class="required">
```

And the result is a working demo.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/KLrs6/580/)

And with `field2` and `field3`:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/KLrs6/584/)

Comment: PLease find this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KLrs6/581/

Comment: Yes, while i change from id to name it works , And may i know the reason why we use name instead of id ?

Comment: The validate plugin like form submission uses the `name` attribute, not the `id` attribute. Any particular reason you want to use `id`'s exclusively?

Comment: Great! Just remember that the keys `field1....` in the validate method refer to `name` attributes.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could be of help.

Answer (score 1):

Check **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/KLrs6/585/)**

Use name attribute in validate NOT ID,Check code

```
<form id="form1" name="form1"> 
     Field 1: <input id="field1" name="field1" type="text" class="required"><br>
     Field 2: <input id="field2"  name="field2" type="text" class="required"><br>
    Field 3: <input id="field3"  name="field3" type="text" class="required"><br>
</form>

<div>
    <input id="btn" type="button" value="Validate">
</div>
```

//JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form1").validate({
        rules: {
            field1: "required",
            field2: "required",
            field3: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            field1: "Please specify your name",
            field3: "Please specify your name"

        }
    })

    $('#btn').click(function() {
        $("#form1").valid();
    });
});
```

Comment: Just now i realized that http://jsfiddle.net/KLrs6/582/ Anyways thanks +1

Comment: @BizDev Welcome ,and please work on improving english a little .Thanks.

Comment: Ahm, thanks. You mean the way i convey or my grammar ?

Comment: @BizDev Both -> `Just now i realized that jsfiddle.net/KLrs6/582 Anyways thanks +1` Here , 1)You need to Capitalize 'I' 2)`I realized that jsfiddle.net` ,This is incomplete sentence. you should use `I realized that jsfiddle.net is working properly.` like this 3)Before Anyway use Fullstop "." as you completed 1st sentence.4)After `Anyway thanks` give fullstop , like `Anyway thanks.`.

Comment: Thanks. I will correct myself.

Comment: I have another problem while implementing this, and i can't ask questions as SO allows only one question for 90 min. Shall we start a chat for this.

Comment: sure no doubt , I love jquery-validate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64834/discussion-between-biz-dev-and-jquery-angry-bird).